# Is it possible to run a game from pygame using WSL and jupyter lab?

Tags: pygame, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to run a Mario Kart clone from a github repository on WSL (Debian), but my WSL doesn't include X11. So, I would like to know if it's possible to launch it from Jupyter lab. When I try to launch it, I get an error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MarioKart.pyw", line 14, in <module>
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(MENU_DIMENSIONS)
pygame.error: No available video device
```

The github repo: https://github.com/s4rd0n1k/pygame_mariokart

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue is a sound issue.  This should be fixed by

> export SDL_AUDIODRIVER='dsp'

Or whatever is necessary to set an environment variable in Jupyter Lab.

Beyond that, I don't know if the graphics will work.

Answer (score 0):

Install XLaunch and run it with all default settings except check "Disable access control"

Next add

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"]="x11"
```

To the top of your python file. This is working for me in WSL 2